# Is there any way to simulate entries for systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I have the following input: `logic SWI[7: 0]`, which I would like to control from another executable, in C ++ for example.

And I have the following outputs: `logic LED[7:0], SEG[7: 0]`, which I would like to get in real time.

Is there any way to simulate systemverilog in such a way that I can simulate inputs and get outputs (in this model)?

Example code that I would like to run:

```
logic T1, T2;
always_comb begin
    T1 <= SWI[0];
    T2 <= SWI[1];

    LED[0] <= T1 && T2;
end
```

I'm sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DPI (C/C++ code linked to the simulation) to get/set values of Verilog signals. Then you can implement some IPC from this DPI code to another executable (e.g. using sockets, pipes etc.).